# Inbound Port Forwarding From One LAN To Another Via OpenVPN Tunnel (PFSense On Both Sides)

Tags: networking, router, firewall, openvpn

I am going to do my best to explain this. Hopefully this isn't too confusing.

Networks (IPs are EXAMPLES and are not actually mine).

***There is a site to site OpenVPN connection setup between Site Alpha and Site Bravo***

**Site Alpha**

WAN 1: 1.1.1.1

LAN 1: 192.168.10.0/24

Port Forwarding (NAT) Rules:

Inbound: Site A is only allowing the OpenVPN ports for the site to site tunnel. No other ports will be authorized for security.

Outbound: The goal (not working right now) is to force ALL outbound traffic over the tunnel and to have it come out via 2.2.2.2 (WAN 2 / Site B).

**Site Bravo**

WAN 2: 2.2.2.2

LAN 2: 192.168.20.0/24

Port Forwarding (NAT) Rules:

Inbound: Any port can be opened but they are only opened on an as needed basis for security.

Outbound: Traffic from both LAN 1: 192.168.10.0/24 AND LAN 2: 192.168.20.0/24 needs to route out to the internet via WAN 2: 2.2.2.2

*Important Note: This is part of a lab I am challenging myself to do. This is not being used in a production environment. But on that same note I would be open to criticism on why this wouldn't be secure.*